# Удаление старых строчек в файле

Tags: c++, qt5

Программа при каждом запуске делает следующее:

```
static FILE *fileDebug;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fileDebug = fopen ("log.txt", "a+t");
    fprintf(fileDebug, "%s Log started\n", QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy").toLocal8Bit().constData());
    ...
}
```

То есть программа пишет свою "историю" в файл. Каждая строчка начинается с даты и времени. В итоге этот лог файл становится всё больше и больше, так что нужно его очищать. Допустим, удалять строчки, написанные больше месяца назад. Как это сделать на qt c++?

Comment: В общем случае - открыть, переписать в новый файл нужные строчки, закрыть, старый файл удалить, новый переименовать...

Comment: mmap + truncate ?

Comment: Лучше использовать цэ++ api для работы с файлами и путями, раз уж метка [tag:c++]

Comment: а можно просто каждую неделю/месяц писать в новый файл, а старый переименовывать в old. Если old есть - удалять. В целом, гуглить на тему "ротация логов". А вот при каждой записи удалять старые записи - себе дороже. Тормозить будет жуть как.

Comment: @KoVadim в дополнение хочу напомнить, что есть такая замечательная утилита как `logrotate` которая все это дело прекрастно автоматизирует